# How To Use Memory Mapped File in Python Linux

Tags: python, image, frames

As I saw in the Python documentation,

https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html.

Python in Linux can fully support the memory-mapped file. However, while I am trying to apply this idea to my application. I cannot run the sample.

My application is that sending the frames from Python file (client) to the another Python file (server).

Client Code

```
import mmap
import time
import os
import cv2 as cv

print("Opening camera...")
cap = cv.VideoCapture('/home/hunglv/Downloads/IMG_8442.MOV')

mm = None
try:
    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        if mm is None:
            mm = mmap.mmap(-1,img.size,mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_WRITE)

        # write image
        start = time.time()
        buf = img.tobytes()
        mm.seek(0)
        mm.write(buf)
        mm.flush()  
        stop = time.time()
        print("Writing Duration:", (stop - start) * 1000, "ms")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
print("Closing resources")
cap.release()
mm.close()
```

Server Code

```
import mmap
import time
import os
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

shape = (1080, 1920, 3)
n = np.prod(shape)
mm = mmap.mmap(-1, n)

while True:
    # read image
    print (mm)
    start = time.perf_counter()
    mm.seek(0)
    buf = mm.read(12)
    img = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape)
    stop = time.perf_counter()

    print("Reading Duration:", (stop - start) * 1000, "ms")
    cv.imshow("img", img)
    key = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    key = chr(key)
    if key.lower() == "q":
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
mm.close()
```

On the server-side, I set the memory index at 0, and try to read the bytes from memory. However, it seems to be that the server cannot read correctly the data from client.

[Updated]
I've tried to read out the first 12 bytes at the server-side. The value is constant, not changing anymore.

> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Besides,
The first 12 bytes of a random frame is

> b'\xf5\xff\xff\xf0\xfa\xfe\xdf\xe9\xed\xd2\xdc\xe0'

Comment: What error are you receiving? Is the data incorrect or not reading at all?

Comment: @rassar I've added the information to the post. The data read from the memory is the same.

Comment: as for me using `-1` in `mmap()` you create two separated `mmaps` and both programs use different `mmap`. You would have to use the same `fileno` in both `mmaps`

Comment: maybe you should rather use `shared-memory` or `pipes` to `sockets` to send from one process to another.

Comment: In the documentation, -1 is anonymous memory, I've tried with another number but it said that the number is not found. I think the two Python files will create differently `mmaps` ( two different objects). That's the reason why server didn't understand the `mmaps` in client.

Comment: I've tried with sockets for sending and receiving the data. However, it leads to another problem: once the connection is established, if a client or a server disconnects the connection, the whole program will be interrupted unexpectedly. That's not a good behavior (may be the server still holding or waiting another connection).

Comment: I found example which probably works but it use `tagName` (the same for client and server) which means it is only for Window - [python-mmap-ipc](https://github.com/off99555/python-mmap-ipc) . Next I found exemple which creates file in `/tmp` to get `file number` and it seems works for me on Linux [Sharing Python data between processes using mmap](https://blog.schmichael.com/2011/05/15/sharing-python-data-between-processes-using-mmap/). I didn't test this code directly but I used this idea in your code and it shows image in client but it is little distorted - maybe I used wrong camera size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I found example which probably works but it uses `tagName` (the same for client and server) and it means it is only for Window:

[python-mmap-ipc](https://github.com/off99555/python-mmap-ipc)

---

Next I found code which works on Linux:

[Sharing Python data between processes using mmap](https://blog.schmichael.com/2011/05/15/sharing-python-data-between-processes-using-mmap/).

It creates real file on disk, resizes it to size of image and then it uses its `fd` in `mmap()`

---

I use web camera for test.

**Server**

```
import mmap
import time
import os
import cv2

print("Opening camera...")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#print(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))  # 640
#print(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)) # 480

shape = (480, 640, 3)
n = (480*640*3)

fd = os.open('/tmp/mmaptest', os.O_CREAT | os.O_TRUNC | os.O_RDWR)
#os.write(fd, b'\x00' * n)  # resize file
os.truncate(fd, n)  # resize file

mm = None
try:
    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        
        if not ret:
            break
        
        if mm is None:
            mm = mmap.mmap(fd, n, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_WRITE)  # it has to be only for writing

        # write image
        start = time.perf_counter()
        
        buf = img.tobytes()
        mm.seek(0)
        mm.write(buf)
        mm.flush()
        
        stop = time.perf_counter()

        print("Writing Duration:", (stop - start) * 1000, "ms")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

print("Closing resources")
cap.release()
mm.close()
```

**Client**

```
import mmap
import time
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

shape = (480, 640, 3)
n = (480*640*3)

fd = os.open('/tmp/mmaptest', os.O_RDONLY)

mm = mmap.mmap(fd, n, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ)  # it has to be only for reading

while True:
    # read image
    start = time.perf_counter()
    
    mm.seek(0)
    buf = mm.read(n)
    img = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape)
    
    stop = time.perf_counter()

    print("Reading Duration:", (stop - start) * 1000, "ms")

    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    key = chr(key)
    if key.lower() == "q":
        break
    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
mm.close()
```

---

**BTW:** probably `mmap()` with `-1` (without creating file on disk) could work with threads (or forks) because they share the same memory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. Now I can fully understand the mechanism behind the `mmap`. I am very happy with your solution. Basically, we need to assign the temporary file in the system (virtual file) and tell two programs access with the same file. 
> https://github.com/off99555/python-mmap-ipc
My approach simply is the same as the link above (unfortunately work only for Window).